# Issue with Facebook Fan Page ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, blogger, facebook-page

I am in the process of making my blog more facebook friendly and my app id for my fan page is causing problems.

Based on the discussion at http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3130433/get-facebook-fan-page-id I checked that my fan page id is 221368874578748 (retrieved from 
https://graph.facebook.com/TapiolanTakamailla )

So I set it to my blog template  like this:

> "meta content='221368874578748' property='fb:app_id'/"

But the debugger gives me error:

> Object at URL
>   'http://www.tapiolantakamailla.com/2012/08/tunnistatko-uuttukyyhkyn.html'
>   of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '221368874578748'
>   for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, 
Tapio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting a Page ID in place of an App ID.

The `fb:app_id` meta tag needs to be an App.
Put the ID of your application there instead. This is on the main page of app settings and on the list of apps you admin

Comment: Thanks for your answer, lgy :-) Your response got me on right track and I figured it out. There seems to be some misleading blog posts on this matter.